# We have similar coins. For real coin the probability of $H$ and $T$ are equal = $\frac{1}{2}$. For fake coin $p(H)=p, 0<p<1,p\neq 0.5$.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We have similar coins from which one is fake. For real coin the probability of $H$ and $T$ are equal = $\frac{1}{2}$. For fake coin $p(H)=p, 0<p<1,p\neq 0.5$. Randomly we select one of those coins.

a) Find probability that chosen coin is not fake given that chosen coin in $n \geq 1$ tosses gave exactly $k \geq 0$ heads.

b) Find probability that choses coin is not fake given that first time for chosen coin $k\geq 1$ heads happened in $n$-th toss

So for a)  $A=$ coin not fake, $B=$ from $n$ tosses exactly $k$ heads

$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = \Large\frac{\binom{n}{k}0.5^k0.5^{n-k}}{p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k}0.5^k0.5^{n-k}}$ last equation derived by law of total probability.

Am I correct? And for b) I think answer should be the same but would be stupid if it is. What's changes in b)?

Comment: For $b)$ you know that the last toss is $T$.  That is not known in $a)$.

Comment: Correction:  should have read "last toss is $H$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct for part a). Your expression for $P(A|B)$ is correct, and the derivation of the law of total probability in the denominator is also accurate.

For part b), we need to adjust our approach since we're now looking at the probability of the coin being real given that the first time we observe $k$ heads is in the $n$-th toss. Let's denote the event "first $k$ heads happen in the $n$-th toss" as event $C$. We want to find $P(A|C)$.

To calculate this, we need to use the negative binomial distribution for the fake coin. The negative binomial distribution models the number of trials required for a fixed number of successes, with a probability of success in each trial.

Let $X$ be a random variable representing the number of trials required to observe $k$ heads (successes) for the fake coin. The probability mass function (pmf) of $X$ is given by:

$$P(X = n) = \binom{n-1}{k-1} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$

For the real coin, the probability of observing $k$ heads in $n$ tosses is the same, with $p$ replaced by $0.5$:

$$P(X = n) = \binom{n-1}{k-1} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-k}$$

Now we can calculate $P(A|C)$ using the law of total probability:

$$P(A|C) = \frac{P(A \cap C)}{P(C)} = \frac{\binom{n-1}{k-1} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-k}}{\binom{n-1}{k-1} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} + \binom{n-1}{k-1} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-k}}$$

Notice that the binomial coefficient in the numerator and denominator is the same, so we can simplify:

$$P(A|C) = \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n}{p^k (1-p)^{n-k} + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n}$$

This is the probability of the coin being real given that the first $k$ heads happen in the $n$-th toss.